# Can the inside parentheses be ignored in simplifying $((x-1)+x^2)((x-1)-x^2)=$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble with

$$((x-1)+x^2)((x-1)-x^2)$$

Can I just ignore the inside parentheses?
And thus the question becomes like this?

$$(x-1+x^2)(x-1-x^2)$$

Has the second equation not changed any value in the first equation?

So the final answer after all the simplification becomes

$$-x^4+x^2-2x$$

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the inside bracket as you did. It is perfectly fine.But the final result would have been :

${(x-1)}^2 - x^4 = x^2 - 2x + 1 - x^4$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2{}{}$